# Node.js and express - Authenticating through OAuth

Tags: node.js, express, oauth

For an application I'm developing, it requires a lot of real-time processing so we've decided to go with Nodejs and using Express to build the application over something like Laravel.

The issue that I'm having is Authenticating the user. Since, we have an OAuth server (Built on Lumen) to authenticate users and provide an API for the mobile application. This application will be reading / writing data on its own and will not really be using the API.

Is it therefore possible to authenticate the user through our OAuth (Store the returned keys)? I'm looking for something similar to `loginusingid` in Laravel

Comment: http://passportjs.org/ might support with some background on how you can authenticate to specify the question a little..

Comment: @R. Gulbrandsen Apologies, I'm not understanding "specify the question a little" ? I am aware of `passportjs` however does this support authenticating using your own API?

Comment: The user's bearer token will be available in the request object and can be validated with either passport or custom middleware before each request gets executed. Short answer to your question is 'yes'. If you have a look at passport or docs about middleware, it would be easier to help you with some code :)

Comment: `serializeUser`, `deserializeUser` and the strategy are used to configure passport

Comment: @R.Gulbrandsen Got it. Looks like I can just use a library such as this (https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-oauth2) authenticate the user and login! Thanks, I didn't realise these were out there.

Comment: Perfect. Happy to help. Passport has a lot of nice out of the box options for authentication. If you want to build it from scratch yourself, You could create your own middleware :) happy hacking

Comment: @R. Gulbrandsen Thanks so much. I'm a bit nervous about moving away from Laravel with this project -- Laravel offers this however it's good to try something new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From github for oAuth2 with Passport https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-oauth2

**Configure the startegy**

```
passport.use(new OAuth2Strategy({
    authorizationURL: 'https://www.example.com/oauth2/authorize',
    tokenURL: 'https://www.example.com/oauth2/token',
    clientID: EXAMPLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: EXAMPLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/example/callback"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
    User.findOrCreate({ exampleId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
      return cb(err, user);
    });
  }
));
```

Now you can authenticate the endpoints either on a global scope

```
express.use(passport.authenticate('oauth2'));
```

or on a route specific location

```
app.get('/auth/example',
        passport.authenticate('oauth2'),
        function(req, res) {
   // Your code here
 });
```

Comment: sorry but I've just thought - how will I be able to pass the username/password using this library? The oauth server I'm using is through an API and therefore it doesn't have the authorise stuff

Comment: it should be returned when the application asks the oauth2 server to validate a token.

Comment: @R Gulbrandsen - thanks for the reply. We don't have /oauth/authorize/ for anything to be returned so I'm struggling to understand how it will return it with the API... In prior systems we just use /oauth/token passing in username/password this then gives us a token providing the username/password is ok

Comment: when your express app sends the token to the oauth server and it is a valid token, the oauth should return the user information. How to create your own oauth server is a bit large question for me to answer in a comment here. So please be specific with your questions :)

Comment: The point I'm trying make, is the fact that our OAuth server does not have /oauth2/authorize/ in it so therefore I cannot use this package. I'm using `passport-oauth2-password-grant` which works fine, however, I am unable to retrieve the 'profile' because I only get a token and a refresh token. Therefore, should I get the token back and then call the API to get the user?